# UK visa from USA - Shipping address

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

I'm sending my passport and supporting documents to the UK consulate for a standard visit visa.  I'm planning to use my own UPS account.  Which address should I mail the packet to?  The consulate general's 845 Third Avenue address or the VFS Broad Street address?

Answer (score 1):

Use the address given in the [directions](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa) at the time you mail the package.

This address has changed over time. It used to be directly to the consulate. Now it isn't.

Today it is:

> VFS Services USA Inc.
>   UKVI Scanning Hub
>   80 Broad Street
>   Floor 6
>   New York, 10004